# Esperanto Internet age abbreviations?

Tags: abbreviations

What are the translations or the equivalents to some of the these most used abbreviations of the internet age?

- **LOL**
- **WTF**
- **OMG**
- ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wiktionary has a [category on internet slang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Esperanto_internet_slang):

- BKV: Bone, kaj vi? -> Good, and you?
- FDK: For de klavaro -> Away from keyboard
- GEVA: Google estas via amiko -> Google is your friend
- KVF: Kiel vi fartas? -> How are you?
- LMS: Laŭ mia scio -> As far as I know/According to my knowledge
- MBR: Mi baldaŭ revenos -> I will return soon
- MDR: Multe da ridoj -> Many laughs (LOL)
- MTR: Mi tuj revenas -> I am returning immediately/I will be right back (BRB)
- ND: Ne dankinde -> You’re welcome
- NG: Ne gravas -> It's not important

Comment: Telegram, the most popular Esperanto chat, do not use GEVA, LMS kaj MTR. However, KV (kaj vi) is often used.

Comment: @Vanege That doesn't mean they are wrong. Are the users of Telegram using different abbreviations for the same things you mention?

Comment: On Telegram, I've seen "MNS" = Mi ne scias.

Answer (score 8):

Some Esperanto computer and internet slang can be found at this site: [Komputeko.](http://komputeko.net/index_en.php)

For example:

- LOL = MDR (multe da ridoj)

Answer (score 3):

I have most commonly seen:

- **mdr** - multe da ridoj (*lots of laughs*) -> "lol" equivalent.
- **bv** - bonvolu (*please*) -> this would be like "pls", but sounds less casual to me; as far as I know "bv." is a common abbreviation in print as well.
- **ndk** - nedankinde (*you're welcome*, lit. *not worth thanking*) -> "yw" equivalent. I suppose **dk** (from "dankon" - *thank you*) would be "ty", but I don't recall seeing it so I don't want to list it.